# Speed up btrfs check --init-extent-tree

Tags: linux, mount, btrfs, fsck

I recently accidentally mounted a btrfs filesystem read-write without knowing a different kernel that also had it mounted read-write was hibernated.  When I resumed the hibernated kernel, it mounted read-only, and when I rebooted, btrfs complained about differing transaction versions and refused to mount at all.

Following a recommendation on the Archlinux forums, I ran `btrfs check --init-extent-tree` on the volume.  So far that process has been running for 4 days and has generated approximately 200MB worth of extents per day.  I have 3TB of data stored on that volume.  If my math is right, it will take 42 years for the process to finish.  For obvious reasons I cannot wait that long.  I should also mention I do not have a backup of this data.

Is there ***anything*** I can do to speed this process up and get my data back sooner?  I am not ruling out modifying and recompiling btrfs-progs.

I should mention I am possibly using an out of date version of btrfs-progs.  I am hesitant to Ctrl+C, update it, and restart the process without knowing for sure whether it would help.

Comment: Might be faster to format the drive and re-populate it with the data.

Comment: Edited to add: I do not have a backup.